# String representation of lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

I hava a `validate_until_true` function which polls the return value from a function until it meets a given condition or timesout.

```
from collections import namedtuple 
import time
A = namedtuple("A", "a b c")

def validate_until_true(f, condition, timeout):
    t = time.time() + timeout
    while time.time() < t:
         v = f()
         if condition(v): return True
         time.sleep(1)
    return False         

class Test:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param=param

    def test(self):
       f = lambda: A(1,2,3)
       print(validate_until_true(f, lambda v: v.a!=self.param and v.b==2, 2))

Test(1).test()
```

I wish to be able to print a message if `validate_until_true` returns False.

Would it be possible to print something along the lines of:

> The condition "v.a!=2 and v.b==2" has not been met, v has the values:
>   a=1, b=2, c=3

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but (AFAIK) you can't really get at the string representation of a function, whether it's been defined using `def` or `lambda`, apart from parsing the source code. And even if you could, I don't think it'd be a useful way to do what you want to do. :)

Anyway, in order for `Test.test()` to print the message you want if `validate_until_true()` returns false `Test.test()` needs access to the final `v` that `condition` tests. In the code you've posted `v` is just a constant, but I assume you want to handle the general case. So you need to change `validate_until_true()` to pass `v` back to its caller. Eg:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from collections import namedtuple 
import time

A = namedtuple("A", "a b c")

def validate_until_true(f, condition, timeout):
    t = time.time() + timeout
    while time.time() < t:
        v = f()
        if condition(v): return True, v
        #print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
    return False, v


class Test:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param=param

    def test(self):
        f = lambda: A(1,2,3)
        condition = lambda v: v.a!=self.param and v.b==2
        result, v = validate_until_true(f, condition, 3)
        if result:
            print('True')
        else:
            msg = 'The condition "v.a!={0} and v.b==2" has not been met, v has the values: {1}'
            print(msg.format(self.param, str(v)[2:-1]))


t = Test(1)
t.test()

p = 7
print('Setting param to {0}'.format(p))
t.param = p
t.test()
```

Does that do what you want, or am I barking up the wrong tree? :)

FWIW, I'm doing this in Python 2.6.